# How do I fetch Firebase Object and set equal to local object?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Ionic app with Angular that uses Firebase as the auth / database.

On my app, the user can create different things, or objects. I then take those objects and put them into an array. So I end up with an array of objects. The user can delete things in that local list, changes things, or add new things.

What I want is to be able to fetch the object (that I successfully store) in Firebase, and set it back as the object. I'm new to Firebase and it's api, so I'm a little stuck. Here's my code to retrieve the object from Firebase:

```
fetchList() {
    const user = this.authService.getActiveUser();
    if (user != null) {
        return firebase.database().ref(user.uid + '/lists').once('value')
            .then( snapshot => {
                return snapshot.val();
            })
            .catch( err => {
                return err;
            });
    }

}
```

I've read all over the Firebase docs and I cant figure out what `snapshot.val()` returns. Does it return an object or what. If it does, will I have to parse through the object to rebuild my local array of objects?

This is an example structure of some data in Firebase. 0 is the array index. I basically just pass in my array of objects and Firebase stores it like this. Now I want to retrieve it and set it equal to my local array of objects, so the user can have

```
+ Sidfnh450dfFHdh989490hdfh
- DFjghd904hgGHdhfs9845hfh0
  - lists
    - 0 
        hasProperty1: false
        isProperty2: false
        otherProperty: 'string stuff here'
        title: 'List Title'
    + 1
    + 2
```

Or maybe I'm going about this all wrong. Maybe there exists a magical Firebase method that's similar to two-way data binding, whatever I change on the local object array mirrors Firebase, and vice versa. Any advice appreciated.

***Edit***

Additionally, something I'm doing locally is reordering the array. My app is a list of some kind, and users can reorder objects in the list. So if I *did* have a synchronized list with Firebase, and someone reordered some objects in the list, I'm not sure how I would reorder them in Firebase without deleting the entire object-array and writing a new one with the updated array indexes.

Comment: Kenny are you using Angular 2/4 or AngularJS? If Angular2/4 then look into `angularfire2` NPM package. It makes integration into firebase much easier.

Comment: You get 3-way data binding so you don't need to store arrays locally -
 it all sits in sync with the firebase database. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: well, there's some things I'm doing locally that I don't think I can do with angularfire2 or firebase, and that's re-ordering an array. I might take something out of the middle and put it a few positions down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adjusted the way you stored the data in Firebase you could pull it out in a predefined order.

Notice the additional `order` key on your list.

```
+ Sidfnh450dfFHdh989490hdfh
- DFjghd904hgGHdhfs9845hfh0
  - lists
    - key1
        hasProperty1: false
        isProperty2: false
        otherProperty: 'string stuff here'
        title: 'List Title'
        order: 1
    + keyn
        // ...
        order: 2
    + keyz
        // ...
        order: 3
```

Within your component you can request that the data comes out in order with a query on the list object.

When saving the new order you can pass the key such as `key1`, `key2` and the new order to the `saveOrder` function.

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: `
    <ul *ngFor="let item of list | async">
      <li>{{ item | json }}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public list: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = this.db.list('/DFjghd904hgGHdhfs9845hfh0/list', { query: { orderByChild: 'order' }});
  }

  saveOrder(key, newOrder) {
    return this.list.update(key, { order: newOrder });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been playing with AngularFire2 and I think I'm going to switch everything over to it. The most difficult challenge was to reorder a list (drag and drop basically) and reflect it in Firebase. But you're right in your answer, I have to store my data differently. :)

Comment: Highly recommend it, also look into https://github.com/firebase/bolt it will make managing the database much easier.